# Who said "he who is in a rush shall walk slowly"?

Tags: literature

A while back I read the saying "he who is in a rush shall walk slowly". I have seen it be attributed to Confucius (https://www.wer-weiss-was.de/t/redewendung-wer-es-eilig-hat-soll-langsam-gehen/8457422 https://www.quotez.net/german/konfuzius.htm) sometimes, but never in any academic reference.

Who is the author of the sentence and where was it written down first?

Comment: I don't know such a quote in the Analects. But interestingly I googled the sentence and found it of Japanese origin.

Answer (score 2):

"he who is in a rush shall walk slowly” was translation of a Japanese proberbs,  and many of them came from Chinese literatures

The idiom [欲速則不達](https://ctext.org/analects/zi-lu/zh?searchu=%E6%AC%B2%E9%80%9F%EF%BC%8C%E5%89%87%E4%B8%8D%E9%81%94%EF%BC%9B%E8%A6%8B%E5%B0%8F%E5%88%A9%EF%BC%8C%E5%89%87%E5%A4%A7%E4%BA%8B%E4%B8%8D%E6%88%90%E3%80%82) (If you rush you are more likely not getting there)  came from 論語 and the writer was 子路.